# How can I remove black dots around hand in image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

using opencv for capturing image in python

i want to make this image :

code for this :

```
# Image Processing
gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (51,51), 15) 
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
ret, test_image = cv2.threshold(th3, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image]

to somewhat like this:

[image]

Comment: You would need to write some code. [ask]

Comment: @Julien Done now can u tell the solution

Comment: Median filter, erosion & dilation operations. You should try some of them.

Comment: You can try DBSCAN too, but i guess it's more computationnaly expensive than solutions listed by @quasimodo

Comment: Delete the black blobs with a small area.

Comment: As usual, OP shows a preprocessed image instead of the original. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll consider [Scikit-Image](https://scikit-image.org/), instead of OpenCV, here's an approach. **It has been edited from my original post, thanks to guiding commentary from @Yves Daoust. This more correct approach runs significantly faster**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import io
from skimage import filters
from skimage import morphology

threshold = filters.threshold_otsu(image)
bimage = np.where(image>threshold,255,0)
rsh_img = morphology.remove_small_holes(bimage,area_threshold=33)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the Chan-Vese segmentation ? IMO removing the holes is good enough.

Comment: This is not OpenCV.

Comment: Yves, my original plan was to use "remove_small_holes()" only, but the results were unsatisfactory. Chan-Vese segmented the original grayscale image into binary regions. You might be able to use a more simple thresholding algorithm instead.

Comment: @Juancheeto: by the way, you  did not notice that the original image is binary  already !

Comment: @YvesDaoust, it's grayscale.

Comment: @Juancheeto: it's not, this is a rescaling artifact. Read the code !

Comment: @YvesDaoust. I've learned something new. Thank you. How do you go about working with an image that has been turned to grayscale due to rescaling?

Comment: @Juancheeto: you don't, you use the full scale image.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Please show us.

Comment: @Juancheeto: 
`ret, test_image = cv2.threshold(th3, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try closing operation. It will do the work.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (51,51), 15) 
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
ret, test_image = cv2.threshold(th3, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)

# opening the image
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(binr, cv2.MORPH_OPEN,
                           kernel, iterations=1)
```

If the resultant image is not good enough then try to increase he kernal size

Comment: No, closing will destroy all fine features... including the edges.

Comment: yes, you are right. I just tested it out and it really is destroying all the features.